# Weird bug in C: Different results to the same function sometimes right sometimes wrong

Tags: c

So I am trying to run this code where I calculate the mean and median in 2 functions. When I use these functions in my main function and run my program, sometimes it gives me the right answer and sometimes it gives me some random numbers for the mean even though I run the exact same code. Can somebody explain this behavior to me?
Any help is appreciated.

```c
    float mean(int *numbers, int n){
        int i=0;
        float solution;
        float tmp_m;
    
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            tmp_m=(float)numbers[i]+tmp_m;
        }
            
        solution=tmp_m/((float)n);
    
        return solution;
    }
    
    float median(int *numbers, int n){
        float median;
        float median_b;
        int index;
        int index_b;
    
        if(n % 2 == 1){
            index=n/2;
            median= (float)numbers[index];
            return median;
    
        }else if (n % 2 == 0){
            index_b=n/2;
            float tmp_median;
            tmp_median= (float)numbers[index_b] + (float)numbers[index_b-1];
            median_b=tmp_median/((float)2);
            return median_b;
    
        }
    }
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main () {
        int array[6]={0,2,3,4,0,5};
        int n=6;
        
        float result=mean(array, n);
        float result_median=median(array, n);
    
        printf("%f\n%f\n", result, result_median);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: Will you give some output, i.e. examples on where it fails and succeeds?

Answer (score 4):

The variable `tmp_m` is left uninitialized and it gives you random values.
So, replace `float tmp_m;` with `float tmp_m = 0;` in the `mean` function.

Answer (score 1):

You haven’t initialised tmp_m to zero before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your tmp_m is not initialized to 0, so it starts out as a random number, which results in an incorrect result